# Storing information in claims

Tags: c#, openid-connect, identityserver4

We are using IdentityServer4 a MVC client application. The MVC client needs information about endpoints that a user is allowed to see. These endpoints are wrapped in a list of objects. Since this is user specific information, we store this information in a Website claim.

My main concern is that this information could get quite large and therfore increasing the size of the request.

Is this good practice to store this kind of information or should we change this and make this a GET request to the IdentityServer to retrieve this object? Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of data does not belong in tokens. Tokens are for conveying identity information over the wire - e.g. a user id.

Build a separate service that returns the authorization data that you need - that will give you much more flexibility.